# How do I read the CLI header from a .NET executable? (in c++)

Tags: c++, .net, clr, portable-executable

I am trying to read the CLI header (also known as the COR20 structure) from an executable coded in C#, in C++, to view its contents.

This is what I've been trying to do, and the "Header" structure has wrong values within itself: the "cb" attribute should always be  0x48, but in my case it's a much higher value, hinting that I am casting wrong data inside it, thus I am not casting the CLI header's data inside it.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
    HANDLE fHandle = CreateFileA("C:\\Users\\MyUser\\OneDrive\\Documenti\\Desktop\\schifo\\Test2Lol.exe", 
    GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    DWORD fSize = GetFileSize(fHandle, 0);

    BYTE* fBuffer = (BYTE*)VirtualAlloc(0, fSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    ReadFile(fHandle, fBuffer, fSize, 0, 0);

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER Dos = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)fBuffer;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS Nt = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(fBuffer + Dos->e_lfanew);
    PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER Opt = &Nt->OptionalHeader;
    PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER File = &Nt->FileHeader;
    
    PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY CLRLocation = &Opt->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR];

    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER Current = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(Nt);
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER CLR = 0;

    for (int i = File->NumberOfSections; i != 0; i--, Current++)
    {
        if (Current->VirtualAddress = CLRLocation->VirtualAddress && Current->VirtualAddress + Current->SizeOfRawData > CLRLocation->VirtualAddress)
            CLR = Current;
    }

    PIMAGE_COR20_HEADER Header = (PIMAGE_COR20_HEADER)CLR;

    return 0;
```

My objective is to find the CLI header inside an executable, and the way inside the code is not the correct way, plus I couldn't find much around the internet.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/5abf1ff7bc05ef47a7680f6a5ea87f3c6f32812c/src/Tasks/StrongNameUtils.cs#L259

Comment: my objective isn't reading the virtual address, but getting to the structure itself. @HansPassant

Comment: although this is useful anyway